# How to get Dropdown Menu with Checkboxes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I am trying for a dropdown menu with checkboxes in it? How do I proceed?
below is my Html snippet I am trying.

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-3">
    <div *ngFor="let option of options">
        <select>
            <input type="checkbox" name="options" value="{{option.value}}" [(ngModel)]="option.checked" /> {{option.name}}
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you need `option` tag inside `select`.

Comment: Yes options can be added, but they dont turn out to be checkboxes, they would be simple options in the drop-down

Comment: Use `input` inside `option`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can easily get from a google search,
Try this

**HTML**

```
<br/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-12">
     <div class="button-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> <span class="caret"></span></button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option1" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option2" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option3" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option4" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option5" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option6" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Option 6</a></li>
</ul>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var options = [];

$( '.dropdown-menu a' ).on( 'click', function( event ) {

   var $target = $( event.currentTarget ),
       val = $target.attr( 'data-value' ),
       $inp = $target.find( 'input' ),
       idx;

   if ( ( idx = options.indexOf( val ) ) > -1 ) {
      options.splice( idx, 1 );
      setTimeout( function() { $inp.prop( 'checked', false ) }, 0);
   } else {
      options.push( val );
      setTimeout( function() { $inp.prop( 'checked', true ) }, 0);
   }

   $( event.target ).blur();

   console.log( options );
   return false;
});
```

or check **[this](https://www.codexworld.com/multi-select-dropdown-list-with-checkbox-jquery/)**,

Comment: Exactly what I needed, Thank you so much.